# Dynamically set validator for @Constraint - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, hibernate-validator

The question is simple as that - is it possible to set dynamically/programmatically a validator for the javax.validation.@Constraint, based on, lets say a flag, from the properties in a Spring Boot application?

My attempt was to declare a custom Validator as interface, which extends ConstraintValidator, and then have 2 specific classes implementing it, each with its own validation method. The type to be validated is the same. But it wouldn't allow me to do that for the interface, nor abstract classes - looks like @Constraint accepts only classes that can be instantiated right away.

Nor I found any example for such approach.

Any idea if it's even possible?

Comment: Why don't you decide inside `public boolean isValid(...)` whether to validate the one or the other way?

Comment: No you cannot. You could determine it in your actual validator and delegate to the one you need.

Comment: @M.Deinum Since you're one of the pros here around, may I ask you to provide a short code example of how you'd do it exactly, thus the best and bulletproof way^^. I'd just make a simple if-else-decision but who am I to tell the way...

Comment: @Slevin, that's how I did. But I was wondering if it's possible to do the way around because for my case it would make more sense to have it split.

Comment: When M.Deinum says that it's not possible, then there is no way. Sometimes you have to go along with what the universe is willing to give...

Comment: Annotations require static metadata, some annotations (mainly those from Spring) can have value expression or SpEL expression in the values. However the constraint annotation is not under the control of Spring (even if you would make it a component it isn't under the control of Spring!) and thus you cannot use value or SpEL expression in those annotations. Only actual classnames. You can let Spring control the instance of the validator and do the routing there, either using an if statement or using an `@Conditional` rule to register the validator to use and let the other inject it.

Comment: @M.Deinum, what you mean is inside the class (MyCustomValidator) which extends ConstraintValidator, thru @ConditionalOnProperty I would delegate injection of one of the "validators" implementations? Something like:
`@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(prop = true)
public ActualValidator()  { return new ActualValidator1(); }

@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(prop = false)
public ActualValidator() { return new ActualValidator2(); }`
And within `MyCustomValidator`:
`@Autowired
private ActualValidator actualValidator;`

Comment: Yup, something like that.